# meteor keycloak third party

Tags: meteor, keycloak

i want to test a keycloak request/response with a keycloak server in a docker file running on my localy machine.

The package Keycloak in atmospherejs doesnt work so i decided to include it to my meteor projekt as a third party library.

I put the library in a public/compatibility/keycloak/keycloak.js

The Autocomplete find it but if i use it then im getting a bug.

Exception while invoking method 'getTestToken' ReferenceError: Keycloak is not defined

But i do not understand it because it is correctly implemented as a thid party library in meteor. Can anybody help me to get this done?

Comment: can you show how you implemented it? have you tried making it a package?

Comment: what do you want to see exactly how i am implemented it? i invoke in the client "in a event" a meteor method how initialize a Keycloak(). no i do not tried it because, that should takes to long time?

Comment: how are you importing the script? are you using script tags? creating a package is pretty easy and fast actually. let me try it with keycloak and will get back to you

Comment: have you tried the npm modules?

Comment: Ok now im understand. i do this in my case to import Keycloak from the library/adapter as keycloak calls.         let test = Keycloak(); in a Javascript file inside the server folder. The library is in a public folder. so there is a reference if a click it throug a IDE like Webstorm. Im landing in the library. But if i invoke them in the runtime i get this bug. thank you for your help and sorry for my bad english

Comment: no dont trie it with npm modules

Comment: with npm modules doesnt work too... it says window not defined....

Comment: with your previous solution when you were calling them as a script, did you try `window.KeyClock`?

Comment: it doesnt works.... window not defined

Comment: in chrome console?

Comment: yes. in both... i tried it on client so the console says that and i tried that on the server side and the terminal says that too....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/mutdmour/meteor-keycloack-adapter) I packaged the [adapter library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-js) for meteor. Have not published it because I need to fork the original library and other stuff. Now you can call KeyCloak() on the client. Here's how I tested it in my router.js:

```
import { Keycloak } from 'meteor/mutdmour:keycloak'

Router.configure({
    waitOn: [
        function() {
            console.log(Keycloak());
        }
    ]
});
```

Here's what you can do to replicate what I did with other libraries:

1. create a package, now you can find it in your packages folder

   `meteor create --package mutdmour:keycloak`
2. copied over the keycloak.js into packages/keycloak
3. changed the package.js file to reference the mainModule to run only on the client. This is why you are getting 'window is not defined'. Because it's running on the server. You could try putting that import in a `if (Meteor.isClient()){...}`

   `api.mainModule('keycloak.js', 'client');`
4. added an export to package.js

   `api.export('Keycloak', 'client');`
5. add the word export to the Keycloak definition in keycloak.js

   `export var Keycloak =`
6. add the package

   `meteor add mutdmour:keycloak`

Comment: ok thank you. but i get now this bug: Cannot find module 'meteor/mutdmour:keycloak' .....

Comment: did you copy it into packages folder (should have /packages/keycloak) and add it `meteor add mutdmour:keycloak`

Comment: go into your folders in terminal and `cd packages/`. There call `git clone https://github.com/mutdmour/meteor-keycloack-adapter.git` and then call `meteor add mutdmour:keycloak`. now if you are using iron router, copy the router code above.

Comment: if it's been added to the project, open up the keycloak.js file in the package folder and put a console.log at the top under `(function( window, undefined ) {` to make sure it's being loaded. then `console.log(window)` in the same place to test if window is being sent.

Comment: ok this works. but now im getting, if i do a check like: keycloak.init().success(function(authenticated) {
            alert(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
        }).error(function() {
            alert('failed to initialize');
        }); ........... i get a exception in the chrome consoles an it says : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.req.onreadystatechange (keycloak.js:599)

Comment: cannot replicated. did you set up a keycloak.json or             `var keycloak = Keycloak({
                        url: 'http://keycloak-server/auth',
                        realm: 'myrealm',
                        clientId: 'myapp'
            });`

Comment: i did only this. it is documented on the docu site of keycloak.         let keycloak = Keycloak();

        keycloak.init().success(function(authenticated) {
            alert(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
        }).error(function() {
            alert('failed to initialize');
        });

Comment: ya, but this still requires a keycloak.json or an object. I get a 404 in console when I don't do either.

Comment: finaly it works for me.. thank you very much mutdmour. you are excellent ;)

Comment: awesome. I am glad :)